# Is Carry Look-Ahead adder used in modern ALUs?

Tags: computer-architecture

I recently came across **carry look-ahead adder**(CLA) in *David and Sarah Harris's book*(Digital Design and Computer Architecture). The circuitry for a 64 bit number (standard integer size in C) is probably huge and gets very complicated.The generate function has just too many gates.

My question is: *are CLAs used in current processors* such as the Intel i3 or in similar series? Also, *are there any better implementations of carry adders?*

I am aware of the fact that older processors like the Intel 8008 and the kind did use a CLA.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29368/do-computers-actually-use-carry-lookahead-adders

Comment: Thank you @Emil. I did see the answer you mentioned prior to asking this question. The answers there were did not satisfy my curiosity. Hence this question.

Answer (score 1):

“Huge and complicated” is no problem, as long as it is fast. It isn’t.

A good choice seems to be a conditional sum adder (CSA) which has a total delay of O(log n) gates. Log n is nice for 64 bit adders.